# Hazelcast 3.4 Backup sync on Cluster Health

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We have 3 node cluster of Hazelcast running in 3.4.1 version. The communication between the nodes are made whit a multicast. Sometimes we see the message "Backup Synchronization in Progress" in Cluster Health section in the home of mancenter and we don't know what this meaning. 
When we have more than 250 puts per second this "alert" appears each 5 minutes and sometimes we have high latency in put Average. 
Someone know what the reason of this message?

Comment: Hi Ivan! Welcome to SO! Would you please correct the spelling & grammar mistakes in your post? "whit" should be "with". "Average" shouldn't be capitalized. The middle of the message has a run-on sentence... "Sometimes ... in ... in ... and ...", which could be broken into multiple sentences. You may also want to clarify "puts" or use back-ticks (left of the 1 key) to `emphasize` them, so that they stand out as a technical term or code. Nice question though! I'm just trying to help illustrate, how to make your posts easier for others to read. :)

Comment: 3.4.1 is a very old version. 3.9 just came out and there have been lot of improvements since then. Try the latest and see if the problem remains. It's anyways impossible to suggest anything without looking at logs. Garbage collection is one of the most common culprit of slowing systems, check gc logs to begin with. "Backup Sync in Progress" means backup partitions are syncing with their primaries.

Comment: Upgrade to 3.9 highly recommended.